# Apache configuring issues

Tags: apache, ubuntu

Recently installed Apache2 on Ubuntu.

I'm having some trouble getting to the page that shows Apache2 has successfully installed.

Running

```
ip addr show eth0 | grep inet | awk '{ print $2; }' | sed 's/\/.*$//'
```

Returns nothing.

Running 'service apache2 status'

```
apache2 is running
```

If I run the command 'apache2' in terminal gives me a list of errors:

```
AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
(13)Permission denied: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:80
(13)Permission denied: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80
no listening sockets available, shutting down
AH00015: Unable to open logs
```

However, using 'sudo apache2' gives me this:

```
[Tue May 26 11:40:48.514878 2015] [core:warn] [pid 4554] AH00111: Config variable ${APACHE_LOCK_DIR} is not defined
[Tue May 26 11:40:48.514923 2015] [core:warn] [pid 4554] AH00111: Config variable ${APACHE_PID_FILE} is not defined
[Tue May 26 11:40:48.514935 2015] [core:warn] [pid 4554] AH00111: Config variable ${APACHE_RUN_USER} is not defined
[Tue May 26 11:40:48.514939 2015] [core:warn] [pid 4554] AH00111: Config variable ${APACHE_RUN_GROUP} is not defined
[Tue May 26 11:40:48.514950 2015] [core:warn] [pid 4554] AH00111: Config variable ${APACHE_LOG_DIR} is not defined
[Tue May 26 11:40:48.519904 2015] [core:warn] [pid 4554] AH00111: Config variable ${APACHE_LOG_DIR} is not defined
[Tue May 26 11:40:48.519999 2015] [core:warn] [pid 4554] AH00111: Config variable ${APACHE_LOG_DIR} is not defined
[Tue May 26 11:40:48.520009 2015] [core:warn] [pid 4554] AH00111: Config variable ${APACHE_LOG_DIR} is not defined
AH00526: Syntax error on line 74 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf:
Invalid Mutex directory in argument file:${APACHE_LOCK_DIR}
```

Not sure if this is related to my problem of trying to find the local server IP that apache is running on.

Any help or guidance is appreciated!

Edit after running ifconfig

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 28:d2:44:db:55:6e  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
          Interrupt:20 Memory:f0600000-f0620000 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:39387 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:39387 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:4256292 (4.2 MB)  TX bytes:4256292 (4.2 MB)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 18:cf:5e:be:29:7a  
          inet addr:10.0.1.15  Bcast:10.0.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::1acf:5eff:febe:297a/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:806787 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:634100 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:880453718 (880.4 MB)  TX bytes:122151075 (122.1 MB)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Going 1 by 1.

```
ip addr show eth0 | grep inet | awk '{ print $2; }' | sed 's/\/.*$//'
```

This will only show something if connections are indeed going through eth0. Run `ifconfig` to see which interface you're using. This will also show you what IP address your machine has.

---

The errors you get after running `apache2` is multiple things.

For `Could not reliably determine the server's`... [you can fix that specific one here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/256013/could-not-reliably-determine-the-servers-fully-qualified-domain-name)

The next three lines complaining about sockets is because apache2 is already running and cannot bind to ports because some other process (the running instance of apache) is already bound to them.

The last line in that block about logs is because you ran apache2 as a non-privileged user and your log files are protected.

---

When you ran apache2 with sudo, you got a whole bunch of errors regarding config variables because you attempted to start apache incorrectly.

`sudo service apache2 start|stop|restart` will load the values from `/etc/apache2/envvars` into your environment prior to starting apache. This is the way you should be controlling apache.

Comment: Thanks for prompt response! I edited my above question with my ifconfig - it seems like I am running eth0? Also, running sudo service apache2 start|stop|restart still gives me the same errors -- any ideas?

Comment: Also if I attempt to access any of the IP's listed in ifconfig, it seems to direct me to my phpinfo page..

Comment: If `sudo service apache2 status` shows that apache is running, then heading to `http://10.0.1.15` should do it. If you're getting back a phpinfo page, looks like everything is good to go?

Comment: Shouldn't I be directed to the Apache default page?

Comment: Theres unfortunately no way for me to know. Its whatever you have at the document root, which is somewhere near `/var/www/html/`.

Comment: Looking at the directory, I see the index file, which has the HTML for the default apache page

Comment: you'll want to check your httpd config files to see where connections are pointing.

Comment: Thanks a ton for pointing that out -- turns out I had it pointing to some other directory (not /var/www/html).